# Calculating $\sum_{\substack{k|r \\ k \leq n}} \mu \left({ {k}}\right)$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, mobius-function

### Background & Question

I recently thought of a combinatoric method to get an interesting result:

$$ \sum_{r=n+1}^{n!} \sum_{\substack{k|r \\ k \leq n}} \mu \left({ {k}}\right) = n! O(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) -1 $$

I was wondering how other methods compared to mine in calculating the quantity:

$$\sum_{\substack{k|r \\ k \leq n}} \mu \left({ {k}}\right)$$

and then summing over to see how it compared to my result? Also is there any method of calculating it without using the Riemann Hypothesis?

### Proof of my method

Consider the following sums: 
$$ 1+1 + 1+ 1+1 +\underbrace\dots_{n! \text{ times}} = n! $$
$$ 0 + 1+ 0+1 +0 +\underbrace\dots_{n! \text{ times}} = \frac{n!}{2} $$
$$ 0 + 0+ 1+0 +0 +\underbrace\dots_{n! \text{ times}} = \frac{n!}{3} $$
We proceed to do so $n$ times:
$$  0+ 0 +\underbrace\dots_{n \text{ times}} +1+\underbrace\dots_{n! \text{ times}} = \frac{n!}{n} $$

Multiplying the $r$th row with $a_r$ which is an arbitrary variable:

$$ a_1+ a_1 + a_1+ a_1+a_1 +\underbrace\dots_{n! \text{ times}} = n! a_1 $$
$$ 0 + a_2+ 0+a_2 +0 +\underbrace\dots_{n! \text{ times}} =n! \frac{a_2}{2} $$
$$ 0 + 0+ a_3+0 +0 +\underbrace\dots_{n! \text{ times}} = n! \frac{a_3}{3} $$
We proceed to do so $n$ times:
$$  0+ 0 +\underbrace\dots_{n-1 \text{ times}} +a_n+\underbrace\dots_{n! \text{ times}} = n!\frac{a_n}{n} $$

Adding all the above equations vertically (as it is a finite sum):

$$ \underbrace{b_1}_{a_1} + \underbrace{b_2}_{a_1+a_2}+ \underbrace{b_3}_{a_1+a_3} + \dots+ b_n +\sum_{r=n+1}^{n!} \tilde b_r = n!\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{a_r}{r}$$

Writing the above properly:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n b_r  + \sum_{r=n+1}^{n!} \tilde b_r = n! \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{a_r}{r} $$

where $b_r =  \sum_{r|k} a_k$ and $\tilde b_r = \sum_{\substack{k|r \\ k\leq n}} a_k $. Using the mobius function we know $ a_{n}=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu \left({\frac {n}{d}}\right)b_{d}$. Re-expressing the expression the above in terms of $b_r$:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n b_r  + \sum_{r=n+1}^{n!} \sum_{\substack{k|r \\ k\leq n}} \sum_{d\mid k}\mu \left({\frac {k}{d}}\right)b_{d}  = n! \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{\sum _{d\mid r}\mu \left({\frac {r}{d}}\right)b_{d}}{r} $$

Applying $\frac{\partial}{\partial b_1} $ both sides:

$$ 1 + \sum_{r=n+1}^{n!} \sum_{\substack{k|r \\ k \leq n}} \mu \left({ {k}}\right) = n! \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{\mu \left({{r}}\right)}{r} $$

Using RH:

$$ 1 + \sum_{r=n+1}^{n!} \sum_{\substack{k|r \\ k \leq n}} \mu \left({ {k}}\right) = n! O(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}) $$

Comment: You’ve put $r\mid k$ but it should be $k\mid r$ in all instances.

Comment: Also, if we go straight from our formula for $n!\frac{a_k}{k}$ to $\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\sum_{d\mid k \\ d\leq n}a_d=n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{k}$, and then use $a_k=\mu(k)$ we have $n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mu(k)}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n!}\sum_{d\mid k \\ d\leq n}\mu(d)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{d\mid k}\mu(d)\right)+\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{n!}\sum_{d\mid k \\ d\leq n}\mu(d)\right)$. Since $$\sum_{d\mid k}\mu(d)=\begin{cases} 1 & n=1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$ we end up with $n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mu(k)}{k}=1+\sum_{k=n+1}^{n!}\sum_{d\mid k \\ d\leq n}\mu(d)$.

Comment: Made it $k|r$ hopefully everywhere

Comment: The title still has $r\mid k$.

Comment: My bad ... fixed now